# Replicating filesystem Samba and Windows

Tags: windows, samba, replication, distributed-filesystems

I'm looking for a way to create a replicating filesystem between Samba and Windows.  I thought that DFSR would be the answer but Samba doesn't support SYSVOL replication.  I also looked at [syncthing](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/syncing.html) but it seemed somewhat resource intensive, because of it's routine scanning of the filesystem.  I feel like I'm missing something, this seems like a pretty common thing to need.

In my case lots of source code is accessible on the Samba server, but Window's compiler performance is poor because of network constraints.  The code is not static so some form of synchronization is needed.

Comment: Why would you want to replicate SYSVOL to a Samba server? Wouldn't you just be replicating your user shares from Windows to Samba?

Comment: If it's just source code replication you're needing, why not look at putting the "source" as Git or similar and having the samba server and the windows servers sync across with Git?  Another option would be to mount the Windows "share" on your Samba server and use cron and rsync to keep them in sync from the linux server.